# How to protect Instagram access key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, instagram, instafeedjs

I'm using Instafeed.js to display the feed in a website, but I've read that's not advisable to let the access token in the client-side.

Is there a way I can protect this data or get the access token in a way it's not visible in the source code? What are the dangers of letting other people see my access key?

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
            accessToken: 'TOKEN_HERE'
}
```

Comment: launder it through php, calling the api with key and spitting out json or whatever from the api without the key

Comment: There's no way to protect it if it's in the browser.  If you want to protect it, you will have to move it to a server, have the browser ask your server for the data, have the server fetch the data from the feed and return it to the client.